# MongoDB C# CRUD

Tags: c#, class, repository

I learned MongoDB recently and I wanted to try it out in C#. I have managed to make the **Update** and **Delete** functions work. I am having issues with the **Create** function.

So, I have three classes named **Program**, **Repository**, **User**.

In **Repository** class, I have:

```
public async Task CreateUser(ConsoleApplication1.Models.User user)
{
    await _collection.InsertOneAsync(user);
}
```

In **Program**, I have following code:

```
ConsoleApplication1.Models.User new_user;   // Declaring Member of User class
string newUserId = Console.ReadLine();      // Taking Input For ID
new_user.id = new ObjectId(newUserId);      // ID
new_user.First_Name = Console.ReadLine();   // First Name
new_user.Last_Name = Console.ReadLine();    // Last Name
new_user.Age = Console.ReadLine();          // Age
new_user.Address = Console.ReadLine();      // Address
r1.CreateUser(new_user);
```

Since in **Repository** class, the **CreateUser** method has only one parameter that is the member of the **User** class and the way I declared the **new_user** in **Program** class, it is not initialized, which is why I am getting error on:

```
new_user.id = Console.ReadLine();
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please edit your question title to describe the problem you are facing, not the technologies and concepts you are using. Please also include enough information for us to help you with your question. For example, you say you're getting an error - what error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before using instance members of class you have to create instance of that class:

```
ConsoleApplication1.Models.User new_user = new ConsoleApplication1.Models.User();
```

Same for your repository - you have to create instance of repository and assign it to variable `r1`.
Further reading [Static vs Instance](https://hackernoon.com/c-static-vs-instance-classes-and-methods-50fe8987b231)

And one more hint - you can use `using` directive to avoid using full type name each time.